# JSON file showing only last entry though ids are different

Tags: javascript, json

My json file looks like:

```
var obj = {
 Dilse : {"name":"Dil Se Re","length":"5:40","songType":"Romantic"},
 Dilse : {"name":"Jiya Jale","length":"3:50","songType":"Self Description"},
 Dilse : {"name":"Chaiyya Chaiyya","length":"4:30","songType":"Masti"},

 Rockstar : {"name":"Sadda haq","length":"5:40","songType":"Romantic"},
 Rockstar : {"name":"Tum ho Pas Mere","length":"3:50","songType":"Self Description"},
 Rockstar : {"name":"Sheher me","length":"4:30","songType":"Masti"},
}
```

I want to retrieve Dilse entries when Dil se is clicked and retrieve Rockstar entries when Rockstar is clicked. I already have Dilse and Rockstar entries at my page.

JS functions look like:

```
function dilSe(){

            document.getElementById("div0").innerHTML = ""; var k =0;
            if(xhr.readyState==4){
            if(xhr.status==200){
                var data=xhr.responseText;
                var arr=eval(data);
                for(var i=0;i<3;i++){             //I dont know if I should itearte like this !?

                            var link=document.createElement('a');
                            link.id='name1'+k++;
                            link.innerHTML="Song Name: " +obj.Dilse.name+"<br/>"+"Song Length: "+obj.Dilse.length+"<br/>"+"Song Type: "+obj.Dilse.songType+"<br/><br/>";
                            console.log("link.id is "+link.id);
                            link.setAttribute('href','#');

                            link.addEventListener('click',albums[link.id]);

                            div0.appendChild(link);
                            } 
                }else{
                    div0.innerHTML="Oops, error in communication!";
                    div0.style.color="red";
                }
            }
}


function rockStar(){

            document.getElementById("div0").innerHTML = ""; var k =0; var r=3;
            if(xhr.readyState==4){
            if(xhr.status==200){
                var data=xhr.responseText;
                var arr=eval(data);
                for(var i=0;i<3;i++){       //I dont know if I should itearte like this !?

                            var link=document.createElement('a');
                            link.id='name2'+k++;
                            link.innerHTML="Song Name: " +obj.Rockstar.name+"<br/>"+"Song Length: "+obj.Rockstar.length+"<br/>"+"Song Type: "+obj.Rockstar.songType+"<br/><br/>";
                            console.log("link.id is "+link.id);
                            link.setAttribute('href','#');
                            console.log("obj.rockstar.name is "+obj.Rockstar.name);
                            link.addEventListener('click',albums[link.id]);

                            div0.appendChild(link);
                            } 
                }else{
                    div0.innerHTML="Oops, error in communication!";
                    div0.style.color="red";
                }
            }
}
```

**BUT at the end all I get is last entry of Dilse (i.e Chaiyya Chaiyya) and last entry of Rockstar (i.e Sheher me) . I want ALL THREE ENTRIES should be displayed.**

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object is incorrect. You evidently cannot have multiple entries with the same key (what you are doing is telling JS: "James is this guy. Ah no, James is this other guy. Ah no again, James is this 3rd guy". Of course, he remembers only the last one.

You need to use arrays. The easiest solution would be to modify your JSON to look like this:

```
var obj = {
 Dilse :
 [
    {"name":"Dil Se Re","length":"5:40","songType":"Romantic"},
    {"name":"Jiya Jale","length":"3:50","songType":"Self Description"},
    {"name":"Chaiyya Chaiyya","length":"4:30","songType":"Masti"},
 ],

 Rockstar :
 [
    {"name":"Sadda haq","length":"5:40","songType":"Romantic"},
    {"name":"Tum ho Pas Mere","length":"3:50","songType":"Self Description"},
    {"name":"Sheher me","length":"4:30","songType":"Masti"},
 ],
}
```

There are other options possible, such as a single array (not associative), with what used to be the key as one of the values inside each object, but that requires you to iterate through the whole array to find stuff you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell how do I iterate in my functions if I have to show all three entries of Dilse or Rockstar ? And how do I use obj.Dilse.name/length/songType in functions to get all 3 entries?

Comment: `var list = obj.Dilse; for (var i = 0 ; i < list.length; i++) { dowatheverwith(list[i].name) } `